# Python convert unicode character to html code and unicode number

Tags: python, unicode, html-entities

Here is what I ultimately want:

A dictionary that holds unicode chars as keys and html code + unicode number as list values.

```
Basic_Latin = {
        ...
        "@": ["U+0040", "&#64;"],
        ...
        }
```

How can this be achieved if only the key is given?

I think of something like this:

```
Basic_Latin = {
        ...
        "@": [to_unicode(@), to_html(@)],
        ...
        }
```

If find a lot of methods for converting the other way round, but not for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that the notations contain is the hexadecimal and decimal value for the Unicode codepoint of the character. That value can easily be obtained by using the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord), then formatting the resulting integer:

```
codepoint = ord('@')
unicode_codepoint = 'U+{:04X}'.format(codepoint)  # four-digit uppercase hex
html_escape = '&#{:d};'.format(codepoint)         # decimal number
```

or as a function:

```
def codepoints(c):
    codepoint = ord(c)
    return ('U+{:04X}'.format(codepoint), '&#{:d};'.format(codepoint))
```

The function returns a tuple rather than a list; presumably this doesn't need to be mutable after all. You probably want to consider using a [`namedtuple` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) so you can also use attribute access.

Demo:

```
>>> def codepoints(c):
...     codepoint = ord(c)
...     return ('U+{:04X}'.format(codepoint), '&#{:d};'.format(codepoint))
...
>>> codepoints('@')
('U+0040', '&#64;')
```